# Couchbase C SDK install issue

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-16.04, couchbase

I need to install the cbc tool.

On my ubuntu 16.04 host I tried to install couchbase C SDK following these [instructions](https://developer.couchbase.com/server/other-products/release-notes-archives/c-sdk):

```
# Only needed during first-time setup:
wget http://packages.couchbase.com/releases/couchbase-
release/couchbase-release-1.0-4-amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i couchbase-release-1.0-4-amd64.deb
# Will install or upgrade packages
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libcouchbase-dev libcouchbase2-bin build-essential
```

Result:

```
$ sudo apt-get install libcouchbase-dev libcouchbase2-bin build-essential
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
build-essential is already the newest version (12.1ubuntu2).
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libcouchbase2-bin : Depends: libcouchbase2-libevent (= 2.8.4-1) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libevent-core-2.0-5 (>= 2.0.10-stable) but it is not installable
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Any idea about fixing the problem?

Comment: I tried the commands on my ubuntu 16.04 and everything worked fine. Please have a check you apt source.list. Maybe you're missing some repository.

Comment: Thanks Mario Santini to point me in the right direction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed: it was a wrong ubuntu `sources.list` setting.

I post here the fix for future references:

The content of `/etc/apt/sources.list` was:

```
deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main
```

(probably an installation error introduced previously with a wrong yarn setup)

To fix the problem all I needed was a right sources list setup, for example:

```
###### Ubuntu Main Repos
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main universe multiverse
deb-src http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial main

###### Ubuntu Update Repos
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-security main universe multiverse
deb http://it.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ xenial-updates main universe multiverse
```